# Быстрая трансформация XML -> XSLT C# на Debian -- как компилировать?

Tags: c#, c, mono

Написал 4 скрипта трансформации XML через XSLT шаблоны. Тестировал на файлах XML 4Мб.

PHP: 50 минут. Python: 30 минут. Java: 15 секунд. C#: 9 секунд.

Сначала хотел внедрять трансформацию шаблонов на Java, но это тащит за собой JVM, потребляет память. В общем ставить на сервер, где работает большой сайт, не очень, т.к. Java там не используется. А специально её ставить неохота. В принципе мне по скорости нравится C#, но можно ли откомпилировать C# на Debian в какую то утилиту? Или туда надо тащить целый ворох зависимостей .NET?

Программка очень простая, буквально 3 строки кода.

```cs
XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
xslt.Load(xsl);
xslt.Transform(xml, html);
```

Для Windows я собираю файл такой командой

```powershell
csc xslt.cs
```

Но как я вижу, получается очень маленький файл (4кб), скорее всего надо, чтобы фреймворки стояли... Вот вопрос, как компилировать под Debian и какие зависимости в нагрузку.

Comment: можешь поставить на дебиан dotnet.core

Comment: [xsltproc](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/xsltproc)

Comment: Пробовал эту утилиту более полу часа мучает файл. Не подходит

Comment: Dotnet core это опять же какая то среда выполнения? Типа как у явы? Или компилирует приложение в автономный исполняемый файл?